# What is the difference between COUNT(*) and COUNT(*) OVER()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Take the following code example:

```
SELECT MaritalStatus,
       COUNT(*) AS CountResult
       COUNT(*) OVER() AS CountOverResult
       FROM (schema).(table)
       GROUP BY Marital Status
```

`COUNT(*)` Returns all rows ignoring nulls right?

What does `COUNT(*) OVER()` do?

This question came in a practice exam so I didn't have the data to query.  I have been using Adventure Works and this site http://www.sqlishard.com/Exercise to practice.

If I enter a query like

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT(*)' , COUNT(*) OVER() AS 'COUNT(*) OVER()'
FROM Customers
GROUP BY ID
```

into the practice site I get 3794 rows returned with the `Count(*)` column full of ones and the `Count(*) Over()` column full of the total number of rows.  I didn't understand this pattern (sorry) so I came here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> COUNT(*) Returns all rows ignoring nulls right?

I'm not sure what you mean by "ignoring nulls" here. It returns the number of rows irrespective of any `NULL`s

```
SELECT COUNT(*)       
FROM (VALUES (CAST(NULL AS INT)),
             (CAST(NULL AS INT))) V(C)
```

Returns `2`.

Altering the above query to `COUNT(C)` would return `0` as when using `COUNT` with an expression other than `*` only `NOT NULL` values of that expression are counted.

Suppose the table in your question has the following source data

```
+---------+---------------+
|  Name   | MaritalStatus |
+---------+---------------+
| Albert  | Single        |
| Bob     | Single        |
| Charles | Single        |
| David   | Single        |
| Edward  | Married       |
| Fred    | Married       |
| George  | NULL          |
+---------+---------------+
```

The query

```
SELECT MaritalStatus,
       COUNT(*) AS CountResult
FROM   T
GROUP  BY MaritalStatus
```

Returns

```
+---------------+-------------+
| MaritalStatus | CountResult |
+---------------+-------------+
| Single        |           4 |
| Married       |           2 |
| NULL          |           1 |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Hopefully it is obvious how that result relates to the original data.

> What does `COUNT(*) OVER()` do?

Adding that into the `SELECT` list for the previous query produces

```
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
| MaritalStatus | CountResult | CountOverResult |
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
| Single        |           4 |               3 |
| Married       |           2 |               3 |
| NULL          |           1 |               3 |
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Notice that the result set has 3 rows and CountOverResult is 3. This is not a coincidence.

The reason for this is because it logically operates on the result set after the `GROUP BY`.

`COUNT(*) OVER ()` is a windowed aggregate. The absence of any `PARTITION BY` or `ORDER BY` clause means that the window it operates on is the whole result set.

In the case of the query in your question the value of `CountOverResult` is the same as the number of distinct `MaritalStatus` values that exist in the base table because there is one row for each of these in the grouped result.

Answer (score 4):

`count(*)`, you can think it as count everything, including NULLs

`count(*) over()` will count how many rows in your result set, in your case, because you did `GROUP BY` on `[ID]` column, which I assume it is a column with primary key (unique values and no null values), then in your case, `count(*)` returns same value as `count(*) over ()` does.

You can test it on other columns with duplicated values and null values.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer, even though it is correct, concise, and much clearer.

Answer (score -3):

Count(*) over () returns the resultset number from your query whether you have a condition or not.